# Azure DSC extension for ARM, powershell script will not update

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, dsc

I'm having trouble getting the DSC extension to update the resources on an ARM provisioned VM in azure.

Here is the ARM template resource I'm using:

```
{
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/dscExtension')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Desired State Configuration"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "forceUpdateTag": "1.012",
        "settings": {
          "wmfVersion": "latest",
          "modulesUrl": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', parameters('DSCConfigurationFile'))]",
          "sasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]",
          "configurationFunction": "[parameters('DSCConfigurationFunction')]",
          "properties": {
          }
        },
        "protectedSettings": { }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
```

I've attempted [Update the LocalConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/metaconfig) and [Using the forceUpdateTag](https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/blob/master/VMDSCInstallFile/azuredeploy.json) -- both of these options seem to have no effect.

Here is CommandExecution.log

```
[05/09/2016 20:17:00.25] Executing: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin\enable.cmd 
[05/09/2016 20:17:02.08] Execution Complete.
######
Execution Output:
Waiting for install to complete...
Install completed.
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0>powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin\enable.ps1 -StartAsyncProcess  0<nul 
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:01] Retrieving status of current request...
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02]     Sequence Number     : 0
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02]     Previous Sequence   : 0
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02]     RebootPending       : False
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02]     RebootNodeIfNeeded  : False
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02]     UseExisting         : False
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02]     State               : Completed
VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T20:17:02] The request for Sequence Number 0 was already processed; will exit.
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0>exit 0 


Execution Error:

######
Command C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin\enable.cmd of Microsoft.Powershell.DSC has exited with Exit code: 0
Plugin (name: Microsoft.Powershell.DSC, version: 2.17.0.0) completed successfully.
```

Notable, there are several commandexecution*.log files being output, one for each deployment, but only 1 DscExtensionHandler*.log

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         5/9/2016   8:17 PM           1331 CommandExecution.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:15 PM           1331 CommandExecution_12.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:12 PM           1331 CommandExecution_11.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:09 PM           1331 CommandExecution_10.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:07 PM           1331 CommandExecution_9.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:05 PM           1331 CommandExecution_8.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:03 PM           1331 CommandExecution_7.log
-a----         5/9/2016   8:01 PM           1331 CommandExecution_6.log
-a----         5/9/2016   7:59 PM          24686 DscExtensionHandler.0.20160509-195436.log
-a----         5/9/2016   7:54 PM           2305 CommandExecution_5.log
```

Here is the most recent DscExtensionHandler*.log

```
(C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\Status\0.status)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:58] Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager: 

    ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
    AgentId                        : E3E292F1-161F-11E6-80C8-000D3A3076AA
    AllowModuleOverWrite           : False
    CertificateID                  : 
    ConfigurationDownloadManagers  : {}
    ConfigurationID                : 
    ConfigurationMode              : ApplyAndMonitor
    ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
    Credential                     : 
    DebugMode                      : {All}
    DownloadManagerCustomData      : 
    DownloadManagerName            : 
    LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0, 2.0}
    LCMState                       : Idle
    LCMStateDetail                 : 
    LCMVersion                     : 2.0
    StatusRetentionTimeInDays      : 10
    PartialConfigurations          : 
    RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
    RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
    RefreshMode                    : PUSH
    ReportManagers                 : {}
    ResourceModuleManagers         : {}
    PSComputerName                 : 

    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:58] Executing Start-DscConfiguration...
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:58] Settings handler status to 'transitioning' 
    (C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\Status\0.status)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:58] [VERBOSE] Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = 
    SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' = 
    root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:58] [VERBOSE] An LCM method call arrived from computer WB01 with user sid S-1-5-18.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:58] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:59] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [DSCEngine] Importing the module 
    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DscResources\MSFT_RoleResource\MSFT_RoleResource
    .psm1 in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:59] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [DSCEngine] Importing the module 
    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DscResources\MSFT_ScriptResource\MSFT_ScriptReso
    urce.psm1 in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:59] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [DSCEngine] Importing the module 
    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DscResources\MSFT_PackageResource\MSFT_PackageRe
    source.psm1 in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:59] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [DSCEngine] Importing the module 
    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DscResources\MSFT_ServiceResource\MSFT_ServiceRe
    source.psm1 in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:54:59] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [DSCEngine] Importing the module C:\Program 
    Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xWebAdministration\1.10.0.0\DscResources\MSFT_xWebsite\MSFT_xWebsite.psm1 in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:00] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[File]textfile]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[File]textfile]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]textfile] The system cannot find the file 
    specified.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]textfile] The related file/directory is: 
    C:\dsc.txt.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[File]textfile]  in 0.0310 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[File]textfile]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]textfile] The system cannot find the file 
    specified.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]textfile] The related file/directory is: 
    C:\dsc.txt.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[File]textfile]  in 0.0000 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[File]textfile]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[File]HangfireDirectory]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[File]HangfireDirectory]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]HangfireDirectory] The system cannot find 
    the file specified.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]HangfireDirectory] The related 
    file/directory is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Onf.Web.Hangfire.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[File]HangfireDirectory]  in 0.0150 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[File]HangfireDirectory]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]HangfireDirectory] The system cannot find 
    the file specified.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[File]HangfireDirectory] The related 
    file/directory is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Onf.Web.Hangfire.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[File]HangfireDirectory]  in 0.0940 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[File]HangfireDirectory]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[WindowsFeature]IIS]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[WindowsFeature]IIS]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:01] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[WindowsFeature]IIS] Importing the module 
    MSFT_RoleResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[WindowsFeature]IIS] The operation 
    'Get-WindowsFeature' started: Web-Server
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[WindowsFeature]IIS] The operation 
    'Get-WindowsFeature' succeeded: Web-Server
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[WindowsFeature]IIS]  in 1.3380 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Skip   Set      ]  [[WindowsFeature]IIS]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[WindowsFeature]IIS]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization] 
    Importing the module MSFT_RoleResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization] The 
    operation 'Get-WindowsFeature' started: Web-AppInit
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization] The 
    operation 'Get-WindowsFeature' succeeded: Web-AppInit
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization]  in 
    0.2500 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Skip   Set      ]  [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[WindowsFeature]ApplicationInitialization]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_ScriptResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy]  in 0.0930 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_ScriptResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy] Performing the 
    operation "Set-TargetResource" on target "Executing the SetScript with the user supplied credential".
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy] GET 
    http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01DC28EA-638C-4A22-A57B-4CEF97755C6C/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi with 0-byte 
    payload
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:02] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy] received 5951488-byte 
    response of content type application/octet-stream
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy]  in 0.7570 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[Script]DownloadWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Package]InstallWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Package]InstallWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_PackageResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] 
    Validate-StandardArguments, Path was C:\WindowsAzure\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] The path extension was 
    .msi
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Parsing 
    {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1} as an identifyingNumber
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Parsed 
    {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1} as {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1}
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Ensure is Present
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] product installation 
    cannot be determined
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] product as boolean is 
    False
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] The package Microsoft 
    Web Deploy 3.6 is not installed
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Package]InstallWebDeploy]  in 0.0930 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[Package]InstallWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_PackageResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] 
    Validate-StandardArguments, Path was C:\WindowsAzure\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] The path extension was 
    .msi
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Parsing 
    {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1} as an identifyingNumber
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Parsed 
    {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1} as {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1}
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Ensure is Present
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] product installation 
    cannot be determined
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] product as boolean is 
    False
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] The package Microsoft 
    Web Deploy 3.6 is not installed
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] 
    Validate-StandardArguments, Path was C:\WindowsAzure\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] The path extension was 
    .msi
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Parsing 
    {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1} as an identifyingNumber
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Parsed 
    {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1} as {ED4CC1E5-043E-4157-8452-B5E533FE2BA1}
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:03] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Package configuration 
    starting
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:06] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Starting 
    C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe with /i "C:\WindowsAzure\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi" /quiet /quiet ADDLOCAL=ALL
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:55:06] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Package]InstallWebDeploy] Starting process 
    C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe with arguments /i "C:\WindowsAzure\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi" /quiet /quiet ADDLOCAL=ALL
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[Package]InstallWebDeploy]  in 265.9510 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] Settings handler status to 'transitioning' 
    (C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\Status\0.status)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_PackageResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource 
    functionality with error message: The return code 1603 was not expected. Configuration is likely not correct 
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Script]SetupWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Script]SetupWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Script]SetupWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_ScriptResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Script]SetupWebDeploy]  in 0.0150 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Skip   Set      ]  [[Script]SetupWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[Script]SetupWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Service]StartWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Service]StartWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Service]StartWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_ServiceResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Service]StartWebDeploy] Startup type for service 
    'WMSVC' is 'Manual'. It does not match 'Automatic'.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Service]StartWebDeploy]  in 0.0630 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[Service]StartWebDeploy]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Service]StartWebDeploy] Importing the module 
    MSFT_ServiceResource in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:29] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[Service]StartWebDeploy] Service 'WMSVC' already 
    exists. Write properties such as Status, DisplayName, Description, Dependencies will be ignored for existing services.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:32] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[Service]StartWebDeploy]  in 2.4770 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:32] [ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ServiceResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource 
    functionality with error message: Failure starting service 'WMSVC'. Please check the path 
    'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\wmsvc.exe' provided for the service. Message: 'Exception calling "WaitForStatus" with "2" 
    argument(s): "Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed."' 
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:32] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[xWebsite]CompanySite]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:32] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[xWebsite]CompanySite]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:32] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[xWebsite]CompanySite] Importing the module 
    MSFT_xWebsite in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:36] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[xWebsite]CompanySite] The Ensure state for 
    website "hangfire.onfulfillment.com" does not match the desired state.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:36] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[xWebsite]CompanySite] The target resource is not 
    in the desired state.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:36] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[xWebsite]CompanySite]  in 3.6200 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:36] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[xWebsite]CompanySite]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:36] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[xWebsite]CompanySite] Importing the module 
    MSFT_xWebsite in force mode.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:36] [VERBOSE] [WB01]:                            [[xWebsite]CompanySite] Performing the operation 
    "Set Item" on target "Item: ConfirmPreference Value: High".
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:38] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[xWebsite]CompanySite]  in 2.9560 seconds.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:38] [ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xWebsite  failed to execute Set-TargetResource 
    functionality with error message: Failure to add certificate to web binding. Please make sure that the certificate thumbprint 
    "?XXXXXXX" is valid. Error: "Value does not fall within the expected range.". 
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:38] [VERBOSE] [WB01]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:38] [ERROR] The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:38] [VERBOSE] Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:38] [VERBOSE] Time taken for configuration job to complete is 280.052 seconds
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:39] Settings handler status to 'transitioning' 
    (C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\Status\0.status)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:39] Updating execution status (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Azure\DSC\ExecutionStatus)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:39] DSC configuration completed.
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:39] Removing meta.mof and mof files...
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:39] Resetting metaconfiguration...
    0
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:39] Settings handler status to 'error' 
    (C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\Status\0.status)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:40] Loading Event Source assembly for telemetry...
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:40] [Telemetry] Invoking [Configuration][End] event for telemetry.[Status]: Failure
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:40] Updating execution status (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Azure\DSC\ExecutionStatus)
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:40] Transitioning to Completed state ...
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:40] Removing file 
    C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\ExtensionHandler.Lock.0.dsc
    VERBOSE: [2016-05-09T19:59:40] Removing file 
    C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\ExtensionHandler.Lock.dsc
```

This above script is from a older deployment (the dsc artifact has since changed)

Lastly, the zip file reference seems to always point to the same location on each deploy:

```
{
  "runtimeSettings": [
    {
      "handlerSettings": {
        "protectedSettingsCertThumbprint": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "protectedSettings": "XXXXXXX",
        "publicSettings": {"wmfVersion":"latest","modulesUrl":"https://XXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/onf-storage-hangfire-artifacts/DSC6451f1662.zip","sasToken":"?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%3D&se=2016-05-09T23%3A52%3A43Z&sp=r","configurationFunction":"ConfigureWebServer.ps1\\Main","properties":{}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The only option that has been successful so far is to remove the VM and start over from scratch

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're deploying this against an already running VM? I don't think that will work, it will likely check for the existence of the VM and consider the whole  thing deployed. (I could be wrong, I've never tried a configuration like that, but it sounds likely)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the intention for DSC is to run it as many times as needed since we are restoring state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem.

Looks like capturing the server where the DSC extension already installed was the source of the problem

The steps taken to resolve the dsc extension setup were as follows:

1) Uninstalled the DSC extension, by running
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin\uninstall.cmd

**Note:** Edited the cmd file (rem lines below), as it was cd'ing to the wrong folder:

```
@echo off
rem 
rem Uninstall is a no-op for the DSC extension.
rem

rem if exist %CD%\bin_dev (
rem    set bin_root=%CD%\bin_dev
rem ) else (
rem    set bin_root=%CD%\bin
rem )

set bin_root=%CD%


echo Cleaning up registry key - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Azure\DSC\ExecutionStatus

@echo on
powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File %bin_root%\uninstall.ps1 < nul

echo Uninstall completed.
```

2) Cleared the 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\RuntimeSettings\0.settings
file

3) Re-captured the machine, redeployed the template

Notable, that the *forceUpdateTag* works as expected now :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you deploy this template you will have to update the value of "forceUpdateTag" otherwise the request will be ignored. If you are updating "forceUpdateTag" every time and still nothing is happening, then collect the logs from the VM and share it. Log collection tool is available @ https://github.com/PowerShell/xDscDiagnostics

Comment: Will try this shortly -- I've updated my original question with the results of the DSC filename change. Now that its running the correct DSC artifact, I will try your suggested answer!

Comment: Posted my results... your time is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Found a forum post related to the script extension not reprocessing. Here is the solution. Change the VM scale set property upgradePolicy to Automatic.
[How to force VM created with an ARM template + CustomScriptExtension to redownload the script and run it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723567/how-to-force-vm-created-with-an-arm-template-customscriptextension-to-redownlo)

```
 "properties": {
    "overprovision": "true",
    "upgradePolicy": {
      "mode": "Automatic"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your post -- unfortunately I cannot easily recreate my original issue as it requires imaging the machine with the DSC extension installed. 
My answer that was posted has instructions on how to remove the extension then create the image of the VM; I'd be very interested to see if the machine can be imaged with DSC installed and have it honor this setting.
I will definitely come back and mark this as the answer if I get the opportunity to test this solution (it would be far easier to pass this as a parameter than it would be to re-image the VM without the DSC extension installed)